# Running ASP.NET website on Microsoft office Live?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ms-office

Does MS Office Live allows user to upload and use asp.net websites? We have a specific requirements where we need to upload and use the our own modules..

I understand the security where it is dangerous for MS to allow user to port their ASPX and dlls into the server..

I would like to any other options to run custom ASPx on MS Office Live

**someone please add office-live tag to the post

Comment: Tag added for now, but this isn't really _programming_ related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do any custom server side programming on Microsoft Office Live. If you need specific custom requirement, have you tried other hosting services?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office Live won't allow server side processing. Azure may be the answer for hosting Asp.Net apps.